# Duplicate the virtual environment for production

Tags: django, nginx, cherrypy

This may be a silly question, but I would still like to ask:

I am developing a project using Django, CherryPy, and Nginx. I noticed that a file `requirement.txt` is usually created to indicate the packages and versions installed in the development environment. Suppose the directory of the virtual environment is `/home/me/project/python2Venv`.

When I deploy my Django project (*tango*) into production, the project is copied to the production directory:

```
sudo cp -r /home/me/project/tango /webapps/tango
```

For the virtual environment, may I just copy the whole directory using the following command or I should install each of the packages into the production environment again according to `requirement.txt`?

```
sudo cp -r /home/me/project/python2Venv /webapps/tango/python2Venv
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think virtualenv uses absolute paths in some files so recreating the env and installing the packages via requirements.txt would be more safe.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, it is recommended to install the packages with requirements.txt. Copying directory, can end up being a nightmare.

Say in Update 1: 
You have 4 packages each with a specific version(pkg1-ver1, pkg2-ver1, pkg3-ver1, pkg-ver1).

In Update 2: 
You have upgraded one package to its new version(pkg1-ver2). With requirements.txt you would just upgrade that one package. Instead of the copying all the packages(Although, i am not sure how well copying of the directory would work).

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 0):

You should install packages with the file `requirements.txt`.

Or you can use `virtualenvwrapper`. It helps to clone virtual environments locally easily such as `cpvirtualenv`, `rmvirtualenv`, etc.